# Image of a proper class under one-one function is a proper class

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Working under Zermelo-Franenkel set theory. how I can prove following:

Let $V$ be proper class. Let $F : V \rightarrow U$ be a one-one function. Then $U$ has to be a proper class.

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you define *function* here?

Comment: @GitGud: Definable class of ordered pairs which satisfies the condition of a function (and in this case, injectivity).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $U$ were a set, so would $F[V]$ be, by comprehension. And then $G: F[V] \rightarrow V$, defined by $G(x)$ is the unique element $v$ of $V$ such that $F(v) = x$, is a well-defined onto function, and by replacement $V$ would then be a set as well.

Answer (score 2):

If $U$ is a set, by Replacement $V=F^{-1}[U]$ is a set.